# onkeypress add spaces after 4th character

Tags: javascript

```
<td>
    <input type="text" id= "test" name="test" size="22" maxlength="22" value="" onkeypress="onsplkeypressTest()" >
</td>
```

```js
function onsplkeypressTest() {  
    var _newVal = document.getElementById("test").value;
    _newVal = _newVal.split(' ').join('');
    var len = _newVal.length+4;
    var ind = 4;

    while (ind < len){
        _newVal = _newVal.substring(0, ind) + ' ' + _newVal.substring(ind, len); //add space
        ind = ind + 5;
    }

    document.getElementById("test").value = _newVal;
}
```

This gives output `ABCD IJKL NOPQ`
however if I want to enter `EFGH` in between `ABCD` and `IJKL` it wont allow
it - it gets appended at the end: `ABCD IJKL NOPQ EFGH`

What code should be written so that output comes `ABCD EFGH IJKL NOPQ`?

Comment: Are you looking for something to format credit card numbers?

Comment: no my requirement is either to add text in single text box like this 
onkey press after fourth character automatically space should get added 
ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOP
and user can edit from any position

or have four text box
and if user copy complete 16 digit and paste in first text box
remaining text should get added in 2nd, 3rd and fourth text box

Answer (score 0):

Change event to onkeyDown, which helps in tracking the key which key is pressed.

Next event.jeycode give the key code, 13 is for enter and 8 is for back space, for these button your code should not be executed.

```
 <input type="text" id="test" name="test" size="22" maxlength="22" value="" onkeydown="onsplkeypressTest()" />


 <script type='text/javascript'>
        function onsplkeypressTest(e) {
            if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
                //code to execute here
                return true;
            }
            else if (event.which == 8 || event.keyCode == 8) {

            }
            else {
                var _newVal = document.getElementById("test").value;
                _newVal = _newVal.split(' ').join('');

                var len = _newVal.length + 4;

                var ind = 4;

                while (ind < len) {

                    _newVal = _newVal.substring(0, ind) + ' ' + _newVal.substring(ind, len);//add space

                    ind = ind + 5;

                }

                document.getElementById("test").value = _newVal;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Even this code gets added the new text at the end of the string and not in between